# How can I create this game-tree in Latex (with information sets)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am having difficulty creating game tree that looks like:

There are two information sets: one defined for the third stage of the game, and the other defined at the terminal nodes. 
I have been spending too much time on my own trying to figure out, so here I am, asking for help.

[image: sample tree]

So far, I have been able to figure out the first bit.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tikzset{
% Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
% Specify spacing for each level of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=35mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=25mm]
% The Tree
\node(0)[solid node,label=above:{$i$}]{}
child{node(1)[solid node, label=left:{$j$}]{}
child{node[hollow node,label=below:{$(s_{1}^*,s_{2}^*+\tau(\overline{q}-\frac{1}{2}))$}]{} edge from parent node[left]{l}}
child{node[hollow node,label=below:{$(o_1,o_2-c_{\Gamma_6})$}]{} edge from parent node[right]{r}}
edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3]{l}
}
child{node(2)[hollow node, label=below:{$(o_1-c_{\Gamma_6},o_2)$}]{} edge from parent node[right]{r}};
\node[below]at(current bounding box.south){$\Gamma_6$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'd recommend the `forest` package for that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code (even if not giving exactly what you want)? Getting good answers is in general more probable if you provide a good [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I am new to the site and not sure how to post my working example in nice format. I provided my working example.

Comment: Hi, does this look better now? & would I be able to get help in this format?

Comment: Much appreciated! :)

Comment: That looks good. Note however that this is no *draw-this-for-me* service. It is generally best to ask specific questions about problems you face. But this way an answer seems more likely. (However I'm not an expert on Ti*k*Z and will take a while if I really decide to try and write an answer)

Comment: Check out the `istgame` package, which is designed for this sort of tree.  The core TikZ tree drawing methods are almost always the least practical.

Comment: @AlanMunn A better option than `forest` here? I haven't used `istgame`, really, to know. (Its author was using it very effectively to answer questions, so there didn't seem much point.)

Comment: Do you need a west-growing tree? Or did you upload the image rotated?

Comment: @cfr Of course `forest` can do this too, but since `istgame` is designed specifically for this sort of thing, I think it has methods that require very little extra work. Of course the syntax for entering trees is not what we're used to. (And I think the image is rotated.)

Comment: @AlanMunn I know `forest` can. I meant, did you think `istgame` is better? Sounds like it probably is, at least for somebody unfamiliar with either.

Comment: @cfr Yes, it is probably a better choice.

Comment: I need a regular tree, sorry for an rotated photo. I will learn to use itsgame! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Although as a linguist the input method for specifying trees in `istgame` is a bit cumbersome (since we are used to using brackets to show the structure), the `istgame` package is designed specifically for game theoretic trees, and because of this, I would recommend learning it, since it has built-in options for most of the notational conventions in that domain. Here then is a version of your tree using the `istgame` package.  I've also added a version of the tree in your code sample to show how players and actions are added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{istgame}
\begin{document}
\begin{istgame}
   \xtdistance{10mm}{50mm}
   \istroot(0)
     \istb
     \istb
     \endist
   \xtdistance{10mm}{35mm}
   \istroot(1a)(0-1)
     \istb
     \istb
     \endist
   \istroot(1b)(0-2)[null node]
     \istb
     \endist
  \xtdistance{10mm}{20mm}
   \istroot(2a)(1a-1)
     \istb
     \istb
     \endist
   \istroot(2b)(1a-2)
     \istb
     \istb
     \endist
   \istroot(2c)(1b-1)
     \istb
     \istb
     \endist
   \istroot(3a)(2a-1)
     \istb
     \istb
     \endist
   \xtShowEndPoints[oval node]
   \istroot(3b)(2a-2)[null node]
     \istb
     \endist
   \xtHideEndPoints
   \istroot(3c)(2b-1)
     \istb
     \istb
     \endist
   \xtShowEndPoints[oval node]
   \istroot(3d)(2b-2)[null node]
     \istb
     \endist
   \xtHideEndPoints
   \istroot(3e)(2c-1)
     \istb
     \istb
     \endist
   \xtShowEndPoints[oval node]
   \istroot(3f)(2c-2)[null node]
     \istb
     \endist
   \xtInfoset[bend left=30](3a)(3c)
   \xtInfoset[bend left=30](3c)(3e)
   \xtInfoset[bend right=30](3b-1)(3d-1)
   \xtInfoset[bend right=30](3d-1)(3f-1)
\end{istgame}

    \begin{istgame}
\xtdistance{10mm}{30mm}
\xtShowTerminalNodes[oval node]
\istroot(0){i}
    \istb{l}[al]
    \istbt{r}[ar]{(o_1-c_{\Gamma_6},o_2)}
    \endist
\istroot(1a)(0-1){j}[plain node]
    \istbt{l}[al]{(s_{1}^*,s_{2}^*+\tau(\overline{q}-\frac{1}{2}))}
    \istbt{r}[ar]{(o_1,o_2-c_{\Gamma_6})}
    \endist
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Nice. One more thing. Could you add players and actions.

Comment: @InSungCho Yes, the package can do  all of that. It is very well documented.

Comment: (+1) What we need, obviously, is an `istgame` style for Forest :-). @InSungCho You should consider accepting this answer.

Comment: @cfr Most of it wouldn't be hard, but there's the damn empty nodes problem that plagues `forest`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I meant that adding players, actions, and payoffs to your answer might be helpful for the one who first posted the question. (The picture dimly shows them.) Oh, you added below. Thank you.

Comment: @InSungCho my apologies. I wasn't paying attention to who wrote the comment.

Comment: @AlanMunn The apology is mine for missing the question mark in my first comment. In fact, I am surprised that someone uses the \istb period version, various node styles including null node, and auxiliary macros so well. Thank you.

Comment: @InSungCho Well the package *is* well documented. :)  BTW, the package name in the code `istgame-ktug` doesn't match the actual package name, and gives a warning, so you might want to fix that the next time you  push an update to CTAN.

Comment: @AlanMunn The package name was taken care of. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @AlanMunn Indeed. It isn't good at fixed-angle trees.

Comment: @AlanMunn With istgame package have been updated. In the istgame v2, \istb. (period version) is renamed as \istbt (terminal version). So your answer above may need a comment about this change.

Comment: @InSungCho Feel free to edit the answer yourself. I don't really use the package, and so I'd have to relearn the differences... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure forest alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{circ/.style={circle,inner sep=2pt,draw}}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\forestset{special edge/.style={        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (!uu.parent anchor) -- (!u.center) 
    --   (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },      
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={l sep=1cm,s sep=1cm,
    if n children=2{circ,fill}{inner sep=0pt}}
[
 [
  [
   [,alias=buff1
    []
    []
   ]
   [
    [,circ,alias=ruff1,special edge]
   ]
  ]
  [
   [,alias=buff2
    []
    []
   ]
   [
    [,circ,alias=ruff2,special edge]
   ]
  ]
 ]
 [
  [,special edge
   [,alias=buff3
    []
    []
   ]
   [
    [,circ,alias=ruff3,special edge]
   ]
  ]
 ]
]
\draw[dashed] (ruff1) to[bend right] (ruff2)  (ruff2) to[bend right] (ruff3)
(buff1) to[bend left] (buff2) (buff2) to[bend left] (buff3);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]